# Inserting image into Elastislide jquery image viewer

Tags: jquery

Can anybody tell me how to inject one more list item below?

```
 <ul id="carousel" class="elastislide-list">
    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/small/1.jpg" alt="image01" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/small/2.jpg" alt="image02" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/small/3.jpg" alt="image03" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/small/4.jpg" alt="image04" /></a></li>

 </ul>
```

This javascript code does not work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$( '#carousel1' ).elastislide( {minItems : 2} );
$( '#carousel2' ).elastislide( {minItems : 2} );
$( '#carousel3' ).elastislide( {minItems : 2} );

  var $postlink  = $("./ajax/profile.html");
  var $imagelink  = $("./ajax/top_logo2.png");
  var $imagename  = $("iContact");
  var $items1  = $('<li><a href="' +$postlink+'"><img src="'+ $imagelink +'" alt="'+ $imagename +'" /></a></li>');

     $('#carousel1 ul').append($items1);
     $('#carousel1').elastislide( 'add', $items1 );
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your trouble may be the unnecessary wrapping of your strings in jQuery. Try this:

```
var postlink = "./ajax/profile.html";
var imagelink = "./ajax/top_logo2.png";
var imagename = "iContact";
var $items1 = $('<li><a href="' + postlink + '"><img src="' 
    + imagelink + '" alt="' + imagename + '" /></a></li>');
```

Only use `$()` when you need a jQuery object.